# When I use WebDriverWait rather than Thread.sleep I get a StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: selenium, groovy, selenium-webdriver, builder

I am trying to write a Selenium object [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for a [Swagger](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/) page, in [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy). For the purposes of this discussion, my problem code can be reduced down to the following:

```
class SwaggerBuilder {

    WebDriver driver
    def resources

    SwaggerBuilder(WebDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver

        Thread.sleep(2000)

        resources = driver.findElements(By.className("resource")).collectEntries {
            def resourceName = it.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText().replaceFirst("[/]", "")
            [(resourceName): it]
        }
    }

    Object invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {

        if(resources[(name)] == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Resource $name cannot be found.")

        resources[(name)].findElement(By.linkText("List Operations")).click()
    }
}
```

Calling this is very simple (from JUnit3):

```
void test1() {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver()
    driver.get("http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/")

    def petstore = new SwaggerBuilder(driver)    // problem does not get past this line!
    try {
        petstore.not_there()
        fail("Did not catch exception.")
    } catch(NoSuchElementException ex) {
        assertTrue(ex.message.startsWith("Resource not_there cannot be found."))
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        fail("Caught wrong exception: ${ex.class}.")
    }
}
```

The `Thread.sleep(2000)` in the constructor is a horrible eye-sore! I tried to replace it with the following waits:

```
def wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("resource")))
```

or:

```
    def wait = new FluentWait<By>(By.className("resource")).
            withTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
            pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).
            ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException)
    wait.until(new Function<By, Boolean>() {
                def count = 0
                @Override
                Boolean apply(By by) {
                    def oldCount = count
                    count = driver.findElements(by).size()
                    return count == oldCount
                }
            })
```

Both of these produced the same result: "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM" in the closure on the line that starts with `def resourceName = ...`.

The `Thread.sleep(2000)` is the only way that I can make this work right now. I am hoping to replace it with a more browser-friendly / robust wait, so this could work even for pages that load slower than 2 seconds. Any other ideas?

Comment: you're saying the element goes out of attachment in less than 2 seconds?

Comment: I should have been more clear, sorry. The `Thread.sleep(2000)` is the only way that I can make this work right now. I am hoping to replace it with a more browser-friendly wait, so this could work even for pages that load slower than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I load your page, I see in the console `"Loaded SwaggerUI"` three times over. That's your problem: SwaggerUI is loaded 3 times over.

#### How to Figure This Out

So I did this:

1. I put a breakpoint over the line that prints out `"Loaded SwaggerUI"`.
2. I reloaded.
3. When I hit the breakpoint, I took a snapshot of the elements that have the class `resource`:

   ```
   var snap1 = Array.prototype.slice.call(
                   document.getElementsByClassName("resource"))
   ```

   (You have to copy the returned value to an `Array` (with `slice` here) because `getElementsByClassName` returns a *live* collection.)
4. I hit the debugger's continue button.
5. When I hit the breakpoint again, I took a second snapshot (named `snap2`).

Ok now for some tests. If the DOM has not changed, the elements should be identical:

```
> snap1[0] === snap2[0]
false
```

That does not look good. Let's see what's still in the DOM tree:

```
> document.contains(snap1[0])
false
> document.contains(snap2[0])
true
```

The element in the first snapshot is no longer in the tree but the one in the 2nd is.

#### Why The Selenium Error?

The 2 second wait is enough to let Selenium start finding elements after the DOM has stabilized. However, when you tell Selenium to wait until there are visible elements of class `resource` in the page, it waits until SwaggerUI is loaded *for the first time*. At some point when it is processing the elements it first finds, SwaggerUI *loads another time* and then the old elements that it found are no longer in the DOM tree. So it raises a `StaleElementReferenceException` because the element it once found in the DOM tree is no longer there. It's been replaced by an element which is in the same location and structurally identical but Selenium wants the *exact same element* not an identical copy.

Answer (score 1):

After the most *excellent* research / suggestion by @Louis, I ended up using:

```
def wait = new FluentWait<By>(By.className("resource")).
        withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
        ignoring(NoSuchElementException)
wait.until(new Function<By, Boolean>() {
            WebElement res
            Boolean apply(By by) {
                def oldRes = res
                res = driver.findElement(by)
                return res == oldRes
            }
        })
```

If anyone is interested, the [entire Builder can be found on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/sebase/code/HEAD/tree/sebase-groovy/src/test/groovy/net/sourceforge/sebase/pages/SwaggerBuilder.groovy) (still under construction at the time of this writing).

Comment: Have you thought of using Apache MetaModel instead of POI?

Comment: @djangofan I don't get it. I'm not using (Apache?) POI for this. And after reading through Apache MetaModel, I do not get how that would help me in this case either.

Comment: I was referring this this other class in your repository you referenced:  http://sourceforge.net/p/sebase/code/HEAD/tree/sebase-groovy/src/test/groovy/se/technipelago/extract/excel/ExcelBuilder.groovy