# " stale element reference" error happening right after finding the element visible by "wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test.
To find a web element I use:

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driverChrome, 5);
WebElement element= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                .xpath("//td[@class='bla bla']")));
```

and RIGHT after that I use the code below to double click on the element:

```
action.doubleClick(element).build().perform();
```

But is throws `stale element reference`  error.

and When I changed `visibilityOfElementLocated` to `elementToBeClickable` it worked properly,

How could the error happen when I have got the element visible right before double clicking on that?

Comment: Depends on the framework used to build the app. Some redraw the page, even multiple times. The element becomes visible, your test moves on, the page redraws, your element is now stale. Obviously waiting to be clickable is safer, in this case.

Comment: @Siking But I double click right after finding the element visible and I am sure nothing was redraw in this very little time (micro second)

Comment: "stale element reference error" says you are wrong.

Comment: @SiKing Frist of all thanks for your answer, and please post it as the answer, second, so is this better that I always use elementToBeClickable instead of visibilityOfElementLocated even when I don't want to click on the element?

Comment: No if the element is not meant to be clickable, it will never become available by `.elementToBeClickable`! If you notice in `ExpectedConditions`, there are many choices, each for different situation. And you can also write your own custom conditions. Every case is different, even within the same application.

Comment: @SiKing Post as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what framework was used to build the web app, it is entirely possible the app is redrawn **multiple times**. [Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26534383/3124333) that I myself encountered. So what you are seeing in your case is:

1. You are waiting for the element to be visible.
2. Page is drawn, element is visible, your test moves on.
3. After calculating additional components of the page, the page is refreshed. All elements from #2 become stale.
4. Your test tries to manipulate an element from #2.

Of course you cannot use `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()` if it is never intended to be clickable. `ExpectedConditions` has number of conditions and you need to use different ones depending on your situation. You can also write [custom conditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html); Google "fluent wait" to find various examples.

If you use [Page Object model](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects), you can cleanly encapsulate all this for each of your elements.

Comment: is this fine to use " ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()" for text fields ? or in other words, what element are better to be detected by " ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()" ?

Comment: Elements that you can perform a mouse click on: hypertext links, buttons, radio boxes, checkboxes, ...